# Is there any sacred knowledge that I am missing in c# decompiled with Telerik JustDecompile?

Tags: c#, decompiling

Someone provided me with the source code for their utility that I need to reverse-engineer and replace. There are lots of assignments in the code like this:

```
var a = checked(checked(checked((int)SomeArray.Length) - 1) + 1);
```

Is this some design pattern that I am not aware of, or just the way it decompiles

```
var a = SomeArray.Length;
```

Comment: It might be that the code was compiled in a checked context. That said I have no idea what this code is doing. The array length operation in C# actual returns a native int. Maybe the original author was trying to see if the length fit in an int (which it pretty much always will)

Comment: But what about this mysterious `-1+1` mental acrobatics?

Comment: My guess is that the guy is trying to check if the thing could fit in an int and fail at compile time.

Comment: Are you saying someone *wrote* that code (ref "the source code for their utility") or that you decompiled an existing utility and got that out of it? In any case the code makes no sense at all. The only thing this would check, but at runtime, would be that the value of `SomeArray.Length` is not equal to `int.MinValue`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Neither. I was provided with decompiled source code.

Comment: To be honest I've seen some weird output from Telerik's decompiler but I've never seen it "that incorrect". I think this is an artifact of some bad developer in the original utility. There should be no point in continuing this madness however so go with the second example. Unless you're **really** worried that `SomeArray.Length` suddenly starts returning *very* negative values.

Comment: @HansPassant But even in a checked context or program, simply reading `Array.Length` doesn't add the spurious `-1+1` code. The compiler won't remove those in a checked context however so I still think this is more of an artifact from the original program than from the decompiler.

Comment: True.  Hmm.  Maybe it was code that was auto-generated by a VB6 or VBA converter that had Option Base 1 in effect.  Ought to be visible from subsequent array indexing statements.

Answer (score 1):

I've never known a C# compiler to emit extra arithmetic instructions when generating code for `Array.Length`.  In IL, `Array.Length` looks something like this:

```
ldloc.1 // Assuming an array was stored in local slot 1
ldlen
```

Even in a checked context, that's what it looks like.  Now, in IL there is no such thing as a checked context like there is in C#.  IL just has different arithmetic instructions that are checked (e.g. `add.ovf` instead of `add`).

If someone wrote code like this:

```
int length = checked( array.Length - 1 + 1 );
```

The IL code that gets emitted looks something like this:

```
ldloc.1
ldlen
conv.i4
ldc.i4.1
sub.ovf
ldc.i4.1
add.ovf
stloc.2
```

It wouldn't surprise me if the decompiler treats each of those `*.ovf` instructions and the `conv.i4` instruction as having its own checked context.  Reading through the instructions and gradually building up a C# expression would get something like the following:

```
ldloc.1    // array
ldlen      // array.Length
conv.i4    // checked( (int) array.Length )
ldc.i4.1   
sub.ovf    // checked( checked( (int) array.Length ) - 1 )
ldc.i4.1
add.ovf    // checked( checked( checked( (int) array.Length ) - 1 ) + 1 )
stloc.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is going on.

It's because the C# compiler is 'lossy,' in that the C# compiler figures out things like data type conversions, and then outputs those conversions directly into the DLL it's writing. All DLLs are written in [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), which isn't as rich as C#, so complex checks and constructs are translated to more, but simpler, instructions.

For example, C# has the idea of lambda functions, but CIL doesn't, so the C# compiler will generate a class with a method on it, then call that method. E.g;

```
str => str.Length
```

becomes something like

```
class DisplayClass234
{
    public int Execute(string str) 
    {
         return str.Length;
    }
}
```

So then, if you try to decompile, Telerik sees the class "DisplayClass234" rather than the original lambda.

Comment: Does that mean that it was the original developer who added and subtracted 1 to all arrays lengths?

Comment: It looks to me like it's a compiler artifact; I don't see any reason to do it like this unless the developer got themselves convinced of something a bit crazy. If you have access to the JustCompile tool, try writing a very small console app with just a few operations, compile it, then decompile it, and see if that appears in the decompiled code. Also try in the project properties, and maybe try checking and unchecking "allow unsafe code" and "optimize code" to see if they introduce the weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

I won't be surprised if JustDecompile has the bug described by Kyle. I can't really remember getting any support requests involving `checked` so that part of the code hasn't really had a good sound reality check.

The chances are though that if the original code was `checked(SomeArray.Length + 1 - 1)` the compiler would cancel out the 1-1 part so it will never reach the decompiler.

Why don't you ask for the IL of that statement and post it here? Whoever decompiled it should be able to get the IL, too.